# How can I allow autocomplete on materialise css to show suggestions for any keyword typed in the field?

Tags: javascript, forms, search, autocomplete, materialize

Currently I have a materialise css autocomplete field showing suggestions that match the exact search criteria in order:

[example showing suggestions for a search term](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjvK0.png)

However, I would like all suggestions to be shown for any keywords that are entered in. So suggestions should still appear even if the search term is in the wrong order or atleast 1 keyword matches:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qNXM.png)

Is this possible with materialise css as I couldn't see options for this? If not, is there a better framework I could use?

Answer (score 0):

In the Materialize documentation (https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) there is an example that shows suggestions as soon as you enter the first letter so I suppose it is possible.

You should add the code snippet that initialises your autocompletion instance.